# Post JSON data to an asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, backbone.js

I am using the backbone MVC framework for a client side application.  It POSTs JSON data to an asp.net application, NOT an asp MVC app.  How do I receive my JSON data?  Is the JSON string somewhere in the `HttpRequest` object?  Does .NET decode the JSON string?  I want to be able to provide an object or model in C# and use this object when deserializing the JSON string, but where can I access the json string during an HTTP Post action?

Comment: have you looked at JSON.net website

Comment: If you could include what your JavaScript code looks like where you're POSTing data, that would help.

Comment: I am using backbone MVC for my javascript. So i have a model with a few attributes and just call the models save() function.  This basically does an HTTP post with the models attributes as a json string like this: {id:5, name : "ModelName"}

Comment: @DJKRAZE Thanks. JSON.net works nicely.

`Stream s = Request.InputStream;`
`StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s);`
`Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject jObj = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(sr.ReadLine());`
`string name = (string)jObj["name"];`

Comment: sounds good... glad i could ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSON.net worked nicely.

```
Stream s = Request.InputStream; 
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s); 
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject jObj = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(sr.ReadLine()); 
string name = (string)jObj["name"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Fiddler, what does the request look like? I would imagine it would be sending the JSON attached to a specific key field. If there is no key field, then you should just be able to read the `Request.InputStream` directly into a string and then deserialize on that.

Comment: The json looks like this: {"id":"10", "name":"doc"} and thats it, its not attached to a specific key field.  I will try deserializing from the Request.InputStream.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:

**How do I receive my JSON data?**
It will be, at a minimum, in your `Request.Form` set of variables (that is, if you're POSTing a form to your ASP.NET page).  It's a name-value collection, so you should be able to access it from there.

**Is the JSON string somewhere in the HttpRequest object?**
Yes - it should be part of `Request.Form`.

**Does .NET decode the JSON string?**
Only if you tell it to.  In WCF services, you can specify what the WebMessageFormat is (XML or JSON).  In MVC, you can handle JSON data accordingly.  You need to handle this either with a custom handler or decode it yourself.

Hopefully this helps.  If you have a specific situation, please provide some sample code or provide more details and I'll update my answer.

Comment: I am not posting a form.  I am using backbone.js to POST a model to the server via the models save() function.  I am not using WCF.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: But if you're still POSTing it to a ASP.NET page that still uses a basic ASP.NET postback model, this should still be relevant.  Actually, most (if not all) of my answer is relevant for ASP.NET MVC.